# How can I use pydub to detect an empty stereo channel

Tags: python, pydub

Some of the audio files I'm working with have an annoying property: they have two channels, but one is empty. This is worse than mono, because the OS happily plays a mono track on both left and right stereo speakers, but these files only play on (for example) the left speaker.

I'd like to detect this with PyDub, but I'm getting a little stuck. If I know a file is bad, I can do:

```
import pydub
bad_sample = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3('bad_file.mp3')
mono_sample = bad_sample.set_channels(1)
mono_sample.export('mono_file.mp3')
```

So far so good. But I can't work out how to automatically detect whether one is bad.

It should be enough to isolate each channel and check whether either is empty. My attempt has been to do something like:

```
import numpy as np
assert bad_sample.sample_width == 2  # hence int16
a = np.fromstring(bad_sample._data,
                  dtype=np.int16)
a = a.reshape((bad_sample.channels, bad_sample.frame_count()))
left = a[0, :]
right = a[1, :]
```

But neither seems to be empty for this bad file, which suggests to me that I'm not reading the format right.

An example case is: http://www.newsonair.com/writereaddata/bulletins/Aurangabad-Marathi-Regional-Bulletins-38645.mp3

Can anyone suggest an easy way to split the channels and detect the empty one?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it turns out I had the stride order wrong. This works:

```
def is_bad_mono(segment):
    if segment.channels != 2:
        return False
    a = np.fromstring(segment._data, dtype=np.uint16)
    a = a.reshape(( int(segment.frame_count()), 2 ))
    threshold = 0.3
    return ((a[:, 0] == 0).mean() > threshold or (a[:, 1] == 0).mean() > threshold)
```

Basically, with the right stride, the bad mono cases are just zero far far more often than they should be if any real sound was coming through.

Hopefully this helps someone else :)